# Is it possible to run fastboot in a recovery mode shell (without connecting to PC)?

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot, shell

I have a method for **unlocking the bootLoader** of my HP SlateBook x2 running Android v4.3 consisting of:

1. Booting into **recovery**.
2. **Connecting** to PC via USB cable.
3. Sending the **command** `fastboot -i 0x03F0 oem unlock` to the Android device.

But this device has an incredible problem: it *sells without USB cable* (LOL), so I have **no USB cable** at all.

But I have **installed TWRP recovery**, that includes a **root command-line shell**. So, as long as I can not connect via ADB bridge by using USB cable nor ADB via Wireless (the recovery mode does not detect the Wi-Fi card), I was wondering if it would be possible to **use this shell** to send the `fastboot` command from recovery mode in the stand-alone device (without any connection to PC, as long as it is not possible).

Any ideas, please?

Comment: I've edited your question to not mention ADB, since `fastboot` is not an ADB command and doesn't use ADB.

Answer (score 1):

Fastboot commands are for the bootloader, not recovery, so even if you send the commands from recovery, it would do no good since you would be in recovery, not the bootloader.

According to all the information I could find about this "tablet," including information from HP, indicates that there is no way to access fastboot since there is no USB port and HP doesn't make a dock-port to USB cable for the tablet. Edit: apparently HP does have a cable for it, but it may be difficult to find and isn't cheap.

Comment: Here ( http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=51682931&postcount=8 ) is the method of rooting the SlateBook by using the Micro-USB dedicated cable (HP spare part number 728141-001, sold separately). It involves the use of several `fastboot` commands.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez that is what you need then. There is no way to access fastboot except from another PC.

Comment: Well, thanks for your opinion. I suggest for you to correct your post, since **there is some USB cable** (expensive, but it exists) for this tablet and **there is a way to access fastboot** for this tablet.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez thanks. It is funny that HP doesn't even list this cable anywhere in their support docs. I am glad there is a way, but it is a very poor design by HP.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late with this answer, but for the future readers, you can unlock your bootloader on-the-fly with an app. Assuming you have root access and a standard unlockable bootloader (`fastboot oem unlock`), you can use [Trickster MOD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bigeyes0x0.trickstermod). You can see its [XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1768315) for more info.

Look under the "Tool" sub-menu and toggle "Bootloader Lock State". If you're even still keeping up with this post, how do you have TWRP with a locked bootloader?

Comment: XDA Thread: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1768315

Link to app on the Play Store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bigeyes0x0.trickstermod&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to send a fastboot command from the device itself. When the device is in fastboot mode, it's a very dumb device and can't even give you a shell or turn on the Wi-Fi. The `fastboot` program is the only way to send it the command to unlock the bootloader.